# Stein shkarchi, Ch3 #5 From Residue formula to real value answer.

Tags: complex-analysis

Question is

Use contour integration to show that

∫Re−2πixξ(1 +x2)2dx=π2(1 + 2π|ξ|)e−2π|ξ|

for all ξ ∈ R

$\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac{e^{2 \pi i x \eta }}{(1+x^2)^2} dx $

I calculate this by residue formula after changing x-> z(complex),

Taking the half-circle contour, residue formula give me the value

$\frac{\pi}{2}(1-2\pi \eta i) e^{2\pi\eta}$.

But the solution is $\frac{\pi}{2}(1+2\pi |\eta| i) e^{-2\pi|\eta|}$

I wonder why the solution changes to real......

Comment: Your expression in the first integral is almost impossible to understand. Please read again the instruction to type properly mathematics with mathjax in this site.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference